# Predict the position of a Rigidbody Object in x second

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

Let's say that you have a `Rigidbody` Object that moves. Force is added to this Object via `Rigidbody.AddForce` or `Rigidbody.velocity`. The Object can roll hit another Object and change direction.

I know about [Extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation) but in this case, it's nearly impossible to use some formula to obtain the position of the object in **x** seconds, since the Object can hit another object and change speed/direction in the process.

Unity 2017 introduced [`Physics.autoSimulation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics-autoSimulation.html) and [`Physics.Simulate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html) to solve this problem. For 2D physics, that is [`Physics2D.autoSimulation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics2D-autoSimulation.html) and [`Physics2D.Simulate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Simulate.html). All I did was first set `Physics.autoSimulation` to false then call the `Physics.Simulate` function.

---

In my example, I wanted to know where a `Rigidbody` would be in `4` seconds after adding force to it, it seems to work fine for tiny seconds like `1`. The problem is that when I pass in bigger numbers like `5` and above, to the `Simulate` function, the predicted position is **not** accurate. It's way way off.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? This problem is worse on Android devices.

My current Unity version is *Unity 2017.2.0b5*.

Below is the sample code I am using. The `guide` GameObject is simply used to display/show where that predicted position is.

```
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public float forceSpeed = 50;

public GameObject guide;

// Use this for initialization
IEnumerator Start()
{
    //Disable Physics AutoSimulation
    Physics.autoSimulation = false;

    //Wait for game to start in the editor before moving on(NOT NECESSARY)
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    //Instantiate Bullet
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);

    Rigidbody bulletRigidbody = obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    //Calcuate force speed. (Shoot towards the x + axis)
    Vector3 tempForce = bulletRigidbody.transform.right;
    tempForce.y += 0.4f;
    Vector3 force = tempForce * forceSpeed;

    //Addforce to the Bullet
    bulletRigidbody.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse);

    //yield break;
    //Predict where the Rigidbody will be in 4 seconds
    Vector3 futurePos = predictRigidBodyPosInTime(bulletRigidbody, 4f);//1.3f
    //Show us where that would be
    guide.transform.position = futurePos;
}

Vector3 predictRigidBodyPosInTime(Rigidbody sourceRigidbody, float timeInSec)
{
    //Get current Position
    Vector3 defaultPos = sourceRigidbody.position;

    Debug.Log("Predicting Future Pos from::: x " + defaultPos.x + " y:"
        + defaultPos.y + " z:" + defaultPos.z);

    //Simulate where it will be in x seconds
    Physics.Simulate(timeInSec);

    //Get future position
    Vector3 futurePos = sourceRigidbody.position;

    Debug.Log("DONE Predicting Future Pos::: x " + futurePos.x + " y:"
        + futurePos.y + " z:" + futurePos.z);

    //Re-enable Physics AutoSimulation and Reset position
    Physics.autoSimulation = true;
    sourceRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    sourceRigidbody.useGravity = false;
    sourceRigidbody.position = defaultPos;

    return futurePos;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are even lucky that the value of `1` worked at-all. You **shouldn't** pass any value above `0.03` to the `Physics.Simulate` or `Physics2D.Simulate` function.

When the value is above `0.03`, you have to it into pieces then use the `Simulate` function in a loop. Decrementing the *x* time while checking if it is still more or equals to `Time.fixedDeltaTime` should do it.

Replace

```
Physics.Simulate(timeInSec);
```

with

```
while (timeInSec >= Time.fixedDeltaTime)
{
    timeInSec -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Your new complete `predictRigidBodyPosInTime` function should look something like this:

```
Vector3 predictRigidBodyPosInTime(Rigidbody sourceRigidbody, float timeInSec)
{
    //Get current Position
    Vector3 defaultPos = sourceRigidbody.position;

    Debug.Log("Predicting Future Pos from::: x " + defaultPos.x + " y:"
        + defaultPos.y + " z:" + defaultPos.z);

    //Simulate where it will be in x seconds
    while (timeInSec >= Time.fixedDeltaTime)
    {
        timeInSec -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    //Get future position
    Vector3 futurePos = sourceRigidbody.position;

    Debug.Log("DONE Predicting Future Pos::: x " + futurePos.x + " y:"
        + futurePos.y + " z:" + futurePos.z);

    //Re-enable Physics AutoSimulation and Reset position
    Physics.autoSimulation = true;
    sourceRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    sourceRigidbody.useGravity = false;
    sourceRigidbody.position = defaultPos;

    return futurePos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late response, but still, in case anyone wants to know how to solve this. So, I read the documentation on rigidbody.velocity, If you add it to the rigidbody's position you will get where the rigidbody will be in 1 second, so if you get the velocity, multiply it by the number of seconds you want to see in the future and then you add it to the rigidbody's position you will get where the rigidbody will be in x seconds, Something like this

```
{
Vector3 PredictionPos(Rigidbody _TargetRb, float _predictiontime){

//get the rigidbodies velocity
Vector3 _targvelocity = _TargetRB.velocity;
//multiply it by the amount of seconds you want to see into the future
_targvelocity *= _predictiontime;
//add it to the rigidbodies position
_targvelocity += _TargetRB.position;
//Return the position of where the target will be in the amount of seconds you want to see into the future
Return _targvelocity;
}
}
```