# How to use Physics.autoSimulation correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to predict the position of a game object using Physics.autoSimulation (the game object has a rigidbody attached).
The problem is that the object has some kind of flickering when I trigger the simulation. Like this:

[image]

I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484868/predict-the-position-of-a-rigidbody-object-in-x-second). I'm starting to think that I'm not using autoSimulation correctly. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestBall : MonoBehaviour {


    public float timeCheck = 3f;
    public float force = 10f;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start () {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }//end Start



    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {

            //Starts the simulation...
            Physics.autoSimulation = false;
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * force, ForceMode.Impulse);
            Vector3 futurePosition = CheckPosition(rb);    
            print("Future position at " + futurePosition);

            //...and move the GameObject for real
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * force, ForceMode.Impulse);

        }//end if

    }//end Update



    Vector3 CheckPosition (Rigidbody defaultRb) {

        Vector3 defaultPos = defaultRb.position;
        Quaternion defaultRot = defaultRb.rotation;

        float timeInSec = timeCheck;

        while (timeInSec >= Time.fixedDeltaTime) {

            timeInSec -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        }//end while

        Vector3 futurePos = defaultRb.position;

        Physics.autoSimulation = true;

        defaultRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        defaultRb.position = defaultPos;
        defaultRb.rotation = defaultRot;

        return futurePos;

    }//end CheckPosition

}//end TestBall
```

It is like for a tiny moment, the game object moves at the end of the simulation and then comes back because the positions resets in `CheckPosition` function.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's your Unity version and can you post animated gif or video of the flickering? I just want to see how bad it is and if it is even possible to fix

Comment: Thanks @Programmer. Added GIF image and Unity´s version is 2017.1.1f1

Comment: Hi, can you try unity 2017.2 before I put an answer? This feature is new and I want to make sure it's not a bug. Also, what are you doing with the `futurePosition` variable

Comment: With version 2017.2.0f1 happens the same thing. I want the future position to program some AI.

Comment: Did you find a fix? I've been experimenting for days and I think I have a fix

Comment: Hi. I was thinking something this weekend and looks like it works but... I don't think is a good solution but tell me what you think: **1.** Cloned the ball and called it "Ghost ball". **2.** Removed its mesh renderer (so it is invisible) and TestBall script. **3.** Put the two balls in a new layer call "Balls" which don't collide between them (Edit > Project settings > Physics). **4.** Create a new property of type rigidbody in TestBall script and attach the Ghost ball in it. **5.** Applied the simulation to the ghost ball (which is the same game object as "ball"). Please, tell me your fix.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't test it. I will do it as soon as I get back to my place. I appreciate your help very much and I will give you feedback as soon as I can. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Physics.autoSimulation` correctly. The problem is how you reset the position.

Modifying Rigidbody's position and rotation is different from modiying its transform's position and rotation. You want to reset the Object's transform with with the transform not the Rigidbody so that the move will happen right away not over multiple frames as that will then make it visible to the screen.

Replace:

```
defaultRb.position = defaultPos;
defaultRb.rotation = defaultRot;
```

with

```
defaultRb.transform.position = defaultPos;
defaultRb.transform.rotation = defaultRot;
```

---

Also, since this is a rolling ball, setting the `velocity` isn't a enough to stop it. You must also set its `angularVelocity` too because the ball is rotating and also translating:

```
defaultRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
defaultRb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
```

This is your new `CheckPosition` function with no flickering:

```
Vector3 CheckPosition(Rigidbody defaultRb)
{

    Vector3 defaultPos = defaultRb.position;
    Quaternion defaultRot = defaultRb.rotation;

    float timeInSec = timeCheck;

    while (timeInSec >= Time.fixedDeltaTime)
    {

        timeInSec -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    }//end while

    Vector3 futurePos = defaultRb.position;


    Physics.autoSimulation = true;

    defaultRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    defaultRb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    defaultRb.transform.position = defaultPos;
    defaultRb.transform.rotation = defaultRot;

    return futurePos;

}//end CheckPosition
```

---

Finally, your current code does not add force on top of the old force. This means that if you press the space key and press it again again, force is not added on top of the old force. Instead, the object is stopped then a new force is added. The old one is lost.

If you want to add new force on top of the old force, you have to store the current velocity and angularVelocity before the simulation then apply them back to the Rigidbody after the simulation. *The object speed should increase over time.*

This has nothing to do with your problem but is just another bug in your code. Below is the fix for this(new `Update` and `CheckPosition` function) :

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        //Get current velocity and angularVelocity
        Vector3 defaultVelocity = rb.velocity;
        Vector3 defaultAngularVelocity = rb.angularVelocity;

        //Starts the simulation...
        Physics.autoSimulation = false;
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * force, ForceMode.Impulse);
        Vector3 futurePosition = CheckPosition(rb, defaultVelocity, defaultAngularVelocity);
        print("Future position at " + futurePosition);

        //...and move the GameObject for real
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * force, ForceMode.Impulse);

    }//end if

}//end Update



Vector3 CheckPosition(Rigidbody defaultRb, Vector3 defaultVelocity, Vector3 defaultAngularVelocity)
{

    Vector3 defaultPos = defaultRb.position;
    Quaternion defaultRot = defaultRb.rotation;

    float timeInSec = timeCheck;

    while (timeInSec >= Time.fixedDeltaTime)
    {
        timeInSec -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    }//end while

    Vector3 futurePos = defaultRb.position;


    Physics.autoSimulation = true;

    //Stop object force
    defaultRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    defaultRb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    //Reset Position
    defaultRb.transform.position = defaultPos;
    defaultRb.transform.rotation = defaultRot;

    //Apply old velocity and angularVelocity
    defaultRb.velocity = defaultVelocity;
    defaultRb.angularVelocity = defaultAngularVelocity;

    return futurePos;

}//end CheckPosition
```

Comment: It works! I thought that I shouldn't mess up with the transorm if I'm using physics but your explanation make all sense. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't move rigidbody object with its transform if you want it to detect collision or trigger but this is different since you are just resetting its position not just moving it around. You are welcome!