# Can we detect when a rigid body collides using Physics.Simulate in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

```
public void RunSimulation()
{
        Physics.autoSimulation = false;
        simulatedBodies = FindObjectsOfType<Rigidbody>().Select(rb => new SimulatedBody(rb)).ToArray();
        striker.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (new Vector3 (200.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f));

        for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++)
        {
            Physics.Simulate(0.02f);
            //GET COLLISIONS HERE 
            if (simulatedBodies.All(body => body.rigidbody.IsSleeping()))
            {
                print(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        Physics.autoSimulation = true;
}
```

I am trying to use physics.simulate in unity. According to unity documentation "**simulation includes all the stages of collision detection, rigidbody and joints integration, and filing of the physics callbacks (contact, trigger and joints**"
I need to get at which iteration does my striker gameobject collides with other gameobject. If I user auto simulation, OnCollisionEnter works. However it doesn't work when I use Physics.Simulate it doesn't register. What am I doing wrong or how do I get when my object collides with other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we detect when a rigid body collides using Physics.Simulate in
>   unity

Yes, it can.

I once did an experiment on this and it worked, I opened the-same sample scene used and made the test again and it worked again. Here is an statement from the doc which is also in your question:

> Simulation includes all the stages of collision detection, rigidbody
>   and joints integration, and filing of the **physics callbacks**
>   (contact, trigger and joints).

So, it can detect collision.

> If I user auto simulation, OnCollisionEnter works. However it doesn't
>   work when I use Physics.Simulate it doesn't register.

You can't use `IsSleeping()` to get collision. Assuming you have collider and Rigidbody properly setup then *the problem is that the `maxIterations` value is **too small** leading to the simulation not being finished and not reaching the destination where it is supposed to collide with another object.* If this collision is not done, `OnCollisionEnter` will not be called.

Increase your `maxIterations` to give it more distance movement in the simulation and `OnCollisionEnter` should be called. As for detecting which iteration your GameObject collides with other GameObject, use a boolean variable as flag and set it to `true` in the `OnCollisionEnter` function then `break` out of the `for` loop when this boolean variable is `true`.

```
const int maxIterations = 60;
int collideIteration = 0;
bool collided = false;

public void RunSimulation()
{
    //RESET OLD VALUES
    collided = false;
    collideIteration = 0;

    Physics.autoSimulation = false;

    Rigidbody rbdy = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rbdy.AddForce(new Vector3(200.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f));


    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++)
    {
        Physics.Simulate(0.02f);

        //Check if collided then break out of the loop 
        if (collided)
        {
            collideIteration = i;

            print(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    Physics.autoSimulation = true;
}

public int GetCollideIteration()
{
    return collideIteration;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    collided = true;
    Debug.Log("Collision: " + collision.collider.name);
}
```

---

If increasing `maxIterations` did not solve your issue then look into [time based simulations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484868/predict-the-position-of-a-rigidbody-object-in-x-second). It will do the simulation in x seconds. `5` seconds is used in the code below and the only thing changes is the `RunSimulation()` function. The rest of the code above is still valid:

```
public void RunSimulation()
{
    //RESET OLD VALUES
    collided = false;
    collideIteration = 0;

    Physics.autoSimulation = false;

    Rigidbody rbdy = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rbdy.AddForce(new Vector3(200.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f));

    //Simulate where it will be in 5 seconds
    float timeInSec = 5f;
    int i = 0;

    while (timeInSec >= Time.fixedDeltaTime)
    {
        timeInSec -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        //Check if collided then break out of the loop 
        if (collided)
        {
            collideIteration = i;

            print(i);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    Physics.autoSimulation = true;
}
```

Comment: You are right it worked. This is a really nice feature by unity.